# Selecting/Assigning multiple columns and rows to array

Tags: vba, excel

I have column structure similar to the below one

```
   Author   Book
    ----    ----
    ----    ----
    Vicky   Book1
    Vicky   Book2
    Giri    Book1
    Giri    Book3
```

The `author` column is in `column B` and `Book` column **might come in any column** based on other column datas

I want to select values in these two columns

I tried

```
fileArray = Range("B4:B" & finalRow & "," & endColumn).Value
```

Here the first part is working fine, `finalRow` contains the row number till which record is there, and endColumn is where the book details will be available

If i use

```
fileArray = Range("B4:B" & finalRow )
```

it is getting values, but when i try to add one more column it is throwing error

Also i tried the below one too

```
fileArray = Range("B4:B9,S4:S9").Value
```

But it is not getting values of `S4:S9`

How can get the desired values?

Comment: Try `fileArray = Range("B4:" & endColumn & finalRow)`. (Assuming that endColumn is a letter, not a number.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim fileArray
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim targetCol As Long

With Sheets("SheetName") ' change to your actual sheet name
    finalRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' assuming "Book" is the column header and headers are in 3rd row
    ' find the correct column number
    targetCol = .Range("B3").EntireRow.Find("Book").Column
    fileArray = Array(.Range("B4:B" & finalRow), _
                .Range(.Cells(2, targetCol), .Cells(finalRow, targetCol)))
End With
```

To get the values:

```
Debug.Print fileArray(0)(1) ' returns Vicky
Debug.Print fileArray(1)(1) ' returns Author1
```

So it's like the 1st parenthesis enclosed number is the column number, the second is the row.